# implementing recycleview in my current project

Tags: python, android-recyclerview, kivy, kivy-language

I am currently working on a kv app and one of the features I want it to have is being able to view a list of files in a certain folder.
I want the files shown in the list to be selectable and pretty much allow me to know which files the user selected in order to do all kind of operations on them.

I've seen the example for recycleview in the kivy documentation but I am having a really hard time to implement it with my current app.

in the following, I showed where I want to add the RV inside the interface

**it is under the screen EditDataBase under the first floatlayout**

that's my current .kv file :

```
<CreateAccountWindow>:
    name: "create"

    namee: namee

    FloatLayout:
        cols:1

        FloatLayout:
            size: root.width, root.height/2

            Label:
                text: "Add a person to the Database"
                size_hint: 0.8, 0.2
                pos_hint: {"x":0.1, "top":1}
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14**4

            Label:
                size_hint: 0.5,0.12
                pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":0.8}
                text: "Name: "
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14**4

            TextInput:
                pos_hint: {"x":0.5, "top":0.8}
                size_hint: 0.4, 0.12
                id: namee
                multiline: False
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14**4


        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.2,"y":0.35}
            size_hint: 0.6, 0.15
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14**4
            text: "Already In the dataset? Request Entry"
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                root.login()

        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.2,"y":0.15}
            size_hint: 0.6, 0.15
            text: "Submit"
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14**4
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                root.submit()


<LoginWindow>:
    name: "login"

    FloatLayout:
    
        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.2,"y":0.5}
            size_hint: 0.6, 0.2
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14**4
            text: "Request Entry"
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "up"
                root.loginBtn()


<MainWindow>:
    n: n
    out: out


    FloatLayout:

        Label:
            id: n
            pos_hint:{"x": 0.1, "top":0.9}
            size_hint:0.8, 0.2
            text: "Username: "

        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.2,"y":0.45}
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.1
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 15**4
            text: "Add a person"
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
                root.createBtn()
        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.5,"y":0.45}
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.1
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 15**4
            text: "Edit permmited residents"
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
                root.deleteBtn()

        Label:
            id: out
            pos_hint:{"x": 0.1, "top":0.4}
            size_hint:0.8, 0.2
            text: "press Out if you would like to go back to the Entry screen\n"


        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.35, "y": 0.1}
            size_hint:0.3,0.1
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 15**4
            text: "Out"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "login"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "down"

<EditDatabase>:

    namee:namee

    FloatLayout:

        *********************************
       /* I want the RV to go in here */
       ********************************

    FloatLayout:
        cols:3

        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0, "y": 0}
            size_hint:0.3,0.1
            text: "Out"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "main"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "down"

        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.35, "y": 0}
            size_hint:0.3,0.1
            text: "Delete"
            on_release:
                root.deleteBtn()



        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.7, "y": 0}
            size_hint:0.3,0.1
            text: "Update"
            on_release:
```

also this is the main file that runs the GUI:

```
Save New Duplicate & Edit Just Text Twitter
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.behaviors.compoundselection import CompoundSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.core.window import Window

from database import DataBase
#from email import send_email
import shutil
import re
import os

class CreateAccountWindow(Screen):
    namee = ObjectProperty(None)


    def submit(self):
        username = self.namee.text
        parent_dir = os.getcwd()+"/Face/Faces/"

        valid_chars = bool(re.match("^[A-Za-z0-9_-]*$", username))
        valid_dir = os.path.isdir(os.path.join(parent_dir,username))

        if(not(valid_chars)):
            invalidUsername()
        elif valid_dir:
            usedUsername()
        elif username == "":
            invalidForm()
        else:
            db.add_user(username)
            self.reset()
            sm.current = "main"

    def login(self):
        self.reset()
        sm.current = "main"

    def reset(self):
        self.namee.text = ""


class LoginWindow(Screen):
    email = ObjectProperty(None)
    password = ObjectProperty(None)

    def loginBtn(self):
        if db.validate() or db.first_login():
            self.reset()
            db.reset_count()
            sm.current = "main"
        else:
            db.inc_count()
            invalidLogin()



    def reset(self):
        pass


class MainWindow(Screen):
    n = ObjectProperty(None)
    current = ""

    def createBtn(self):
        sm.current = "create"

    def deleteBtn(self):
        sm.current = "delete"

    def logOut(self):
        sm.current = "login"




class EditDatabase(Screen):

    namee = ObjectProperty(None)
    

    def deleteBtn(self):
        d = db.delete(self.namee.text)
        if not(d): userDoesntExist()
        self.reset()

    def updateBtn(self):
        db.delete([self.namee.text])
        db.add_user(self.namee.text)
        self.reset()
        

    def reset(self):
        self.namee.text = ''




class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


def invalidLogin():
    pop = Popup(title='Invalid Entry',
                  content=Label(text='Not a resident of this house.'),
                  size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
    pop.open()


def invalidForm():
    pop = Popup(title='Invalid Registration',
                  content=Label(text='Name, Voice Recording and Face Picture \nare required for registration'),
                  size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))

    pop.open()

def usedUsername():
    pop = Popup(title='Used username',
                  content=Label(text='Username is already used'),
                  size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
    pop.open()


def invalidUsername():
    pop = Popup(title='Invalid username',
                  content=Label(text='Username can only contain:\n numbers,a-z,A-Z and ''_'''),
                  size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
    pop.open()

def userDoesntExist():
    pop = Popup(title='Not a Resident',
                  content=Label(text='Name entered is not a resident of the house'),
                  size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
    pop.open()
kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")

sm = WindowManager()
db = DataBase()

screens = ([LoginWindow(name="login"), CreateAccountWindow(name="create")\
,MainWindow(name="main"),EditDatabase(name='delete')])
for screen in screens:
    sm.add_widget(screen)

sm.current = "login"


class SecuritySystem(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm



if __name__ == "__main__":
    SecuritySystem().run()

    # after the application close clean up all the folders
    faces_path = os.getcwd() + '/Face/Faces/'
    if(os.listdir(faces_path)):
        for folder in os.listdir(faces_path):
            shutil.rmtree(faces_path + folder,ignore_errors =True)
    
    residents_path = os.getcwd() + '/VoiceClassification/residents_set/'
    if(os.listdir(residents_path)):
        for voice in os.listdir(residents_path):
            os.remove(residents_path + voice)
```

also another question that I would like to ask is if there's a way to add / remove widgets such as text boxes and labels while the app is running, I tried using remove_widget but it doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: Have you considered using [FileChooser](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.filechooser.html#module-kivy.uix.filechooser)? Or [kivy garden Filechooser](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.filechooserthumbview)?

Comment: Hey now that I see it is quite fitting but is there a way to disable the user from being able to go navigate between directories and force him to stay just on the directory I want him to see?

Comment: also is there an option to make folders selectable and not just files

Comment: Check the documentation [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.filechooser.html#kivy.uix.filechooser.FileChooserController.dirselect) and [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.filechooser.html#kivy.uix.filechooser.FileChooserController.rootpath).